# Why dictionary type data has to be initialized into empty before using again

Tags: jquery, json, dictionary

I have this JSON data and i was updating the datas dynamically based on the users input. My question is why i have to initialize an empty dictionary variable when storing data?

Because when i initialize it only once it overwrites the data for all of my value for that specific key. Im talking about if the code is like this:

```
function updateThirdLayer() {

_data = global_json_data;

$.each(_data, function(key1, value1) {
    if (key1 == 'questions') {
        $.each(value1, function(key2, value2) {
            if (value2["choices_qty"] > 1) {
                choices = {};
                choice = {};
                for (xyz = 0; xyz < value2["choices_qty"]; xyz++) {

                    choice["id"] = value2["choices"][xyz]["id"];
                    choice["description"] = $("#q" + key2 + "_a" + xyz).val();
                    choices[xyz] = choice;
                    console.log(JSON.stringify(choice));
                    console.log(JSON.stringify(choices));
                }
                console.log(JSON.stringify(choices));
            }
        });
    }
});
global_json_data = _data;

}
```

But when i initialize it everytime i will use the variable it gives me the right output. When the code is like this:

```
function updateThirdLayer() {

_data = global_json_data;

$.each(_data, function(key1, value1) {
    if (key1 == 'questions') {
        $.each(value1, function(key2, value2) {
            if (value2["choices_qty"] > 1) {
                choices = {};
                for (xyz = 0; xyz < value2["choices_qty"]; xyz++) {
                    choice = {};
                    choice["id"] = value2["choices"][xyz]["id"];
                    choice["description"] = $("#q" + key2 + "_a" + xyz).val();
                    choices[xyz] = choice;
                    console.log(JSON.stringify(choice));
                    console.log(JSON.stringify(choices));
                }
                console.log(JSON.stringify(choices));
            }
        });
    }
});
global_json_data = _data;

}
```

JSON STRUCTURE:

```
{
"blah":"blah",
"questions":
 {
  0:
  {
  "blah":"blah",
  "choices":
   {
    0:
    {
     "id":"",
     "description":"desc"
    } 
   }
  }
 }
}
```

NOTE: I know that the way i structure my data is a bad way but kindly disregard it. My question is the explanation why it works like that

THANKS A LOT PEOPLE!

EDIT:

When im using the first block of codes above the "DESCRIPTION" of all the choices becomes the value of the last item in choices description for all the data of every description key on choices

global_json_data:

```
{"title":"1","total_qty":"3","per_page":"2","questions":{
  "0": {"description":"1","type_id":"1","choices_qty":1,"choices":null},
  "1": {"description":"2","type_id":"1","choices_qty":1,"choices":null},
  "2": {"description":"3","type_id":"2","choices_qty":"4","choices":{
      "0":{"id":"","description":""},
      "1":{"id":"","description":""},
      "2":{"id":"","description":""},
      "3":{"id":"","description":""}
       }
   }
 }}
```

Comment: can you show the `global_json_data` so that we can create fiddle & check the issue

Comment: Hi agam! I edited the post. Kindly check what you are asking and tell me if its fine :D

Comment: There's quite a lot of functions i did before the JSON data ended like that but as i've mentioned above why do i have to clear the variable for the dictionary which i will use for so many times